# Why does my freshly installed lightningd not show funds that I transferred to it?

Tags: core-lightning

I have a box with Ubuntu, bitcoin: fully indexed, and c-lightning.  I made several new addresses, and put money into one of them.  The money was transferred to it in block 655761.  I see the bech32 address when I run dev-listaddrs, it was sent to the right address.  Why would list funds show no outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clightning actually needs to scan all blocks to check for output's and Adresses it controls.

I assume most likely your c-lightning node is so fresh that it has not seen such a late block yet. Once your c Lightning node is up to date funds appear directly in listfunds once they are confirmed. So I guess you can do two things.

1. Check your log file and see how far c Lightning is with parsing through blocks
2. Wait until clightning is finished